# Issue with setting landscape view in cordova/phonegap app

Tags: android, html, cordova, orientation, phonegap

I have a problem with setting screen of my app to be in horizontal position. Like in the title. Well, at the very beginning I did it adding this line to the config.xml: `<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"/>`. The problem is that it works only in one direction. I mean it rotates the screen only to the left. So I decided to use a cordova plugin and I did so. I have used "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" from npm and I added

```
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
    }
```

to the index.html. And it works fine. The another problem is that some of my files have this line of code:

```
    function onBackKeyDown() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
```

which turns off the app after clicking this arrow on the android bar. And after clicking this button app is admittedly off but it is still in the RAM and after clicking this button (picture)[image: button]
you can get back to it and **then this plugin doesn't work any more.** My app turns to the portrait orientation. And now my question. What can I do to avoid it? Shoud I set it somehow to turn off from the RAM or is there better way to set orientation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you app is reopened/continued from RAM it triggers the [resume event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.resume.html). You can add an event listener for it and lock the screen orientation in the callback function:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
  screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
}
```

Comment: Do I have to add this to all of my pages or only to the first one (index.html)?

Comment: If its not a SPA (Single Page Application) you will have to add it on every page where it is possible to "resume".

Comment: Ok I'll try it. Just give me a sec.

Comment: Ok, I did it but I works not exactly in the way I would like it to work. I "fixes" the orientation but only after blockig my screen. So I'm still able to rotate my screen to portrait but after I block and unblock my phone it works fine.

Comment: You can try [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) plugin to finetune the experience. It offers some useful methods and callbacks.